# How to remove blacklist tag for extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have .crx file for my chrome extension and modify external_extensions.json to install it.

It works correctly but after remove it in UI, there is no way to reinstall it.

According to [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html).

If I uninstall extension through the UI, extension is blacklisted and

I can remove it by install the extension through the UI and uninstall it.

What I wan to know is the way to remove blacklist tag without installing through UI.

Is there any way I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure on that but maybe if you added to the whitelist in policies (I wonder if the blacklists are the same, in which case the whltelist overrides the blacklist)?.....
http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallWhitelist
http://dev.chromium.org/administrators
...if not then consider using policies to install the extension next time and they wont be able to uninstall it.

Comment: There is actually also a description of [ExtensionInstallBlacklist](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallBlacklist). Trouble seems to be that (at least for me, with chrome ver 23) settings the whitelist does not behave as expected, and neither can I find any blacklisted extensions in my registry (after removing the extensions manually in chrome, and searching the Registry for "blacklist"... Anyone has some new info on this?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested yet.
You can try remove your extension id from ExtensionInstallBlacklist.
These configurations location: refert to [policy-templates](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates)